# Direct sum problem in module theory

Tags: modules

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n),p$ a prime $n\ge 0$, regarded as $\mathbb{Z}$-module is not a direct sum of any two non-zero submodules. Does this hold for $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ for other positive nteger ???

---

Please help anyone .

Comment: $\mathbb Z$-modules are just Abelian groups. Do you possibly already know this result from group theory?

Comment: yes i know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition for a module $M$ to be $X\oplus Y$, for nonzero submodules $X$ and $Y$, is that there exist nonzero submodules $X,Y$ such that $X\cap Y=\{0\}$.

Is it possible for $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$? What are the submodules (subgroups)?

Is it possible for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? Yes. Try with $n=6$.

Comment: for $\mathbb{Z}/n p\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/n2\mathbb[Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n 3 \mathbb{Z}$ by CRT, Subgroup of Z/p^nZ are those whose order is divisors of p^n